# Can't activate dynamic disk

Tags: windows, usb, external-hard-drive, dynamic-disk

For some reason I can't activate a dynamic disk connected to my PC via a USB hard disk enclosure. It has activated previously without any problems.

When I check the event logs, I get this message every time I try to activate the disk:

```
dmio: Harddisk2 write error at block 2930277167: status 0xc0000015
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason appears [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/64c8543f-fa27-436b-b857-f876fa82aa64):

> **Dynamic disks are not supported for USB devices.**  The help and MSDN
> say this.  You can fake around it in WinXP by attaching a drive to a
> SATA or IDE port, changing it to dynamic, then putting the drive in a
> USB enclosure.   It appears they decided to enforce this restriction
> in Win7.
>
> That's a drag, as it will make it difficult to mount a drive
> from a different machine on a USB chain, which you sometimes need to
> do to make repairs.

Microsoft is now enforcing the no-USB policy for Dynamic Disks.

If it is a single disk dynamic disk (not spanned or striped to another disk or set of disks), you MAY be able to [convert it to a Basic Disk](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309044).

> **To change a dynamic disk back to a basic disk:**
>
> 1. Back up all the data on all the volumes on the disk you want to convert to a basic disk.
> 2. Log on as Administrator or as a member of the Administrators group.
> 3. Click **Start**, and then click **Control Panel**.
> 4. Click **Performance and Maintenance**, click **Administrative Tools**, and then double-click **Computer Management**.
> 5. In the left pane, click **Disk Management**.
> 6. Right-click a volume on the dynamic disk that you want to change to a basic disk, and then click **Delete Volume**.
> 7. Click **Yes** when you are prompted to delete the volume.
> 8. Repeat steps 4 and 5 for each volume on the dynamic disk.
> 9. After you have deleted all the volumes on the dynamic disk, right-click the dynamic disk that you want to change to a basic disk,
>    and then click **Convert to Basic Disk**.
>
> **NOTE**: You must right-click the gray area that contains the disk title on the left side of the Details pane. For example, right-click
> **Disk 1.**

Answer (score 0):

I ran the manufacturers to test for errors, but it found none. I still can't access the disk, but I was able to use [this tool](http://www.recovermyfiles.com/data-recovery-software-purchase.php) to recover all of my data. I suspect the problem was caused by a dirty shutdown in Windows.

---

I just ended up reformatting the drive in the end

Answer (score 0):

I'd run [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on it to clear up any errors or bad sectors.  I've saved several disks by using it, although I never use bad disks in a production environment after they've started giving errors.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the product here, and provide the link for reference.