# Second partition missing on 4TB drive following update to Windows 10

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

I've just upgraded my PC from Windows 7 to Windows 10 and the second partition on my 4TB drive is not showing in My Computer. In Computer Management the drive is showing a single NTFS partition of 2048GB with the rest of the drive unallocated. The PC has BIOS hence my originally partitioning the drive under Windows 7 to keep each partition below the 2TB limit. However, the partitioning was done some years ago and I don't remember the detail of how I did this. How can I access the missing partition without destroying the data contained within?

Thanks

Comment: Hake a look something similar might have with you -https://superuser.com/questions/544249/whole-working-windows-7-partition-on-ssd-suddenly-became-unallocated-disk-spa

Answer (score 1):

Try out the open source product [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) by Christophe Grenier to find the remains of your missing partition.

Comment: You may wish to consider adding a link to TestDisk's site (highlight _TestDisk_ then click the link button)

Comment: https://www.cgsecurity.org/